# Google OAuth returning error: Invalid response: 400

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For the last few days I've been playing around with the YouTube data API v3 and for some reason, every time I run the code Google provides [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video%5C). Copying the code, pasting in to my own IDE and fixing all the Python 2 to Python 3 errors (for some reason Google still hasn't updated their guide), creating a `client_secrets.json` file with all the correct information, and also replacing the `apiclient` module with `googleapiclient`. I run the script with the args that Google provides:

```bash
python upload_video.py --file="/tmp/test_video_file.flv"
                       --title="Summer vacation in California"
                       --description="Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz"
                       --keywords="surfing,Santa Cruz"
                       --category="22"
                       --privacyStatus="private"
```

all in one line of course, but when I do, I of course get greeted with an authentication screen from my browser (I use Chrome). After logging in and accepting the application, I return to my terminal and see this line: `Authentication has failed: Invalid response: 400.`. This appears at the bottom of the output and is the last thing that prints to the screen before closing the program. I've tried fixing it by watching a lot of tutorials and reading pretty much the whole Google guide on the API, I also read [this page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/oauth.md) and altered my code from here until I got this:

```py
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets.json", scopes=["openid", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"])
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

but this code results in another error, before even being able to get to the API, saying that the token can't be accessed (from `flow.run_local_server()`). I am really lost with this and have no idea how to fix it. If anyone knows the details on the Google OAuth system, please let me know.

I've tried everything. I even used a different machine, made a whole new Google app for this and read the (basically) non-existent documentation... I'd expect a massive corporation like Google to have a very clear and concise guide on stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

After some more grueling testing, I've figured out a way. Sadly however, my videos are still private locked, even with this method, but that is because I'm not verified. You can use the `googleapis` node.js module for the job. I've written a simple script that sends the video information to the YouTube API.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const assert = require("assert");
const {google} = require("googleapis");

const SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json";
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"];
const TOKEN_PATH = "client_oauth_token.json";

const videoFilePath = "video.mp4";

exports.uploadVideo = (title, description, tags) => {
    assert(fs.existsSync(videoFilePath))
    fs.readFile(SECRETS_FILE, function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error loading client secret file: " + err);
            return;
        }
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => uploadVideo(auth, title, description, tags));
    });
}
function uploadVideo(auth, title, description, tags) {
    const service = google.youtube("v3");
    service.videos.insert({
        auth: auth,
        part: "snippet,status",
        requestBody: {
            snippet: {
                title,
                description,
                tags,
                categoryId: 24,
                defaultLanguage: "en",
                defaultAudioLanguage: "en"
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: "public"
            },
        },
        media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream(videoFilePath)
        },
    }, function(err, response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    const clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    const redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
        if(err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: "offline",
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url: ", authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", function(code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error while trying to retrieve access token " + err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}
function storeToken(token) {
    fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Token stored to " + TOKEN_PATH);
    });
}
exports.uploadVideo("", "", []);
```

I have no idea why my previous method doesn't work, but I'll take all that I can get. If you don't want to authenticate every day for this to work, use this function here:

```js
function getAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken) {
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        form: {
            client_id: clientId,
            client_secret: clientSecret,
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            grant_type: "refresh_token"
        }
    }
    return request(options);
}
```

You do however need a refresh token, which is returned in the response of the first authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I have also made another script (in Python this time) to upload the videos. It's much uglier, but does **not** result in you getting private-locked. I couldn't find a way that uses the YouTue data API, and it instead uses Selenium. Here it is:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

def uploadVideo():
    useragent = "" # add your user agent here
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("path/to/profile") # add your profile
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent)
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    sleep(5)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    sleep(5)

    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/upload")
    upload = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/input')
    upload.send_keys("path/to/video") # uploads video, add path to video
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    sleep(5)

    title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[1]/ytcp-ve/ytcp-video-metadata-editor/div/ytcp-video-metadata-editor-basics/div[1]/ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox/ytcp-form-input-container/div[1]/div[2]/div/ytcp-social-suggestion-input/div')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'title_of_video'", title) # add a title

    description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[1]/ytcp-ve/ytcp-video-metadata-editor/div/ytcp-video-metadata-editor-basics/div[2]/ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox/ytcp-form-input-container/div[1]/div[2]/div/ytcp-social-suggestion-input/div')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = 'video_description'", description) # add a description

    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    sleep(5)

    madeForKids = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[1]/ytcp-ve/ytcp-video-metadata-editor/div/ytcp-video-metadata-editor-basics/div[5]/ytkc-made-for-kids-select/div[4]/tp-yt-paper-radio-group/tp-yt-paper-radio-button[2]')
    madeForKids.click() # video not for kids

    next = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[2]/div/div[2]/ytcp-button[2]')
    next.click()
    next.click()
    next.click()

    public = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[1]/ytcp-uploads-review/div[2]/div[1]/ytcp-video-visibility-select/div[2]/tp-yt-paper-radio-group/tp-yt-paper-radio-button[3]/div[1]')
    public.click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    sleep(15)
    publish = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/ytcp-uploads-dialog/tp-yt-paper-dialog/div/ytcp-animatable[2]/div/div[2]/ytcp-button[3]/div')
    publish.click()

    sleep(10)
    driver.quit()
```

Hopefully this is my last little endeavour with the dumpster fire that is this API.